# array iteration using jQuery templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a JavaScript array:

```
var personDetails = [
{firstName: "Anup", lastName: "Vasudeva", City: "Delhi"},
{firstName: "Vikas", lastName: "Kumar", City: "Banglore"},
{firstName: "Dannis", lastName: "Richie", City: "Texas"},
{firstName: "Ajay", lastName: "Sharma", City: "Pune"},
{firstName: "Deepak", lastName: "Aggarwal", City: "Delhi"},
{firstName: "Ajay", lastName: "Sharma", City: "Banglore"}
```

]

and this is the template I intend to design:

```
<div class="left">
     <!-- Should display the first half of the rows -->
     {{tmpl($data) "#someTemplate"}}
</div>
<div class="right">
    <!-- Should display the rest half of the rows -->
    {{tmpl($data) "#personTemplate"}}   
</div>

<script id="personTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each personDetails}}
    <div class="person">
        <div>${firstName}</div>
        <div>${lastName}</div>
        <div>${city}</div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

How can I manipulate the array such that  contains first half of the rows and  contains second half of the rows.

EDIT:
Actually the thing is that the user will pass the array as is and it is the templating logic that will slice the array in two equal halves.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can Silce array in 2 arrays var left = array.slice(0,mid); var right = array.slice(mid);

Comment: Thanks Champ... I have the same idea, but I don't know how to write that in templates. Can you quote an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the templating to manipulate the data in this way. Do it externally before you provide the user given array to the templating. The reason why you don't want to do this is because if you leave to templating to handle such logic it would be utterly slower than doing it externally. This would not be notisable for arrays of 10-20 items, but if the array becomes large for one reason or another then the templating would be notisably slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to slit your input in half:

```
var input = [
    {firstName: "Anup", lastName: "Vasudeva", City: "Delhi"},
    {firstName: "Vikas", lastName: "Kumar", City: "Banglore"},
    {firstName: "Dannis", lastName: "Richie", City: "Texas"},
    {firstName: "Ajay", lastName: "Sharma", City: "Pune"},
    {firstName: "Deepak", lastName: "Aggarwal", City: "Delhi"},
    {firstName: "Ajay", lastName: "Sharma", City: "Banglore"}
];

var half_point = Math.floor(input.length / 2);
var first_half  = input.slice(0, half_point);
var second_half = input.slice(half_point+1)

console.log(first_half, second_half)
```

#### Update

I'm not sure why would you want to do it in the template itself, i would recommend you to move this logic next to the data, maybe by adding a method to the `Array` objects:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function(chunk_count, chunk_no) {
    var chunk_size = Math.floor(this.length / chunk_count);
    return this.slice(chunk_no * chunk_size, chunk_size + chunk_no * chunk_size);
}
```

... and calling it from the template's each method like this:

```
<script id="personTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="left">
    {{each data.chunk(2, 0)}}
    <div class="person">
        <div>${firstName}</div>
        <div>${lastName}</div>
        <div>${city}</div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="right">
    {{each data.chunk(2, 1)}}
    <div class="person">
        <div>${firstName}</div>
        <div>${lastName}</div>
        <div>${city}</div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

It's debatable if extending ("monkeypatching" in other circles) core Classes is a good idea or not, you can add the same function directly to your `input` variable too.
Using two separate variables assigned to the template before rendering however probably causes less surprises and therefore maybe more favourable over this.

Comment: Thanks complex857, I just want to achieve the same in the context of jQuery templates. Can you tell me where this logic will fit in templates? Have edited my question, can you have a look?

Comment: Yes complex857, I realized the approach I was taking to incorporate logic inside templates wasn't performant. Thanks for the solution.